# ng-click is not calling the function i tried all previous answers

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

Am not able to get the function execution with the click on the button. I am new with angularjs I may make a silly mistake. I need suggestions as I tried most of the previous solutions. but still, it's not working for me.

````
<script>
    var app = angular.module("myModule.controller", []);
    app.controller("bar_controller", [ "$scope", "$http", "$window",
            function($scope, $window, $http) {

                $scope.OperationalList = function() {

                    $window.alert("calling function!");
                     $scope.name = data;
                    $http({
                        method : 'post',
                        url : '/com.az.BusinessRationAnalysis/reportGenerate',


                    }).then(function(result) {
                        $window.alert("succeed " + result.data);
                        req.data={"nome":$scope.name}; 
                        $scope.jsonOperationalDataList = result.data;

                    }, function(result) {
                        $window.alert("Ajex call failed");


                    });

                }

            } ])
</script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myModule.controller">
    <div ng-controller="bar_controller">
        Name:<input type="text" data-ng-model="name" />
        <button ng-click="OperationalList()">Display Report</button>
 <p>Hola {{name}}</p>
    </div>
    ```
I need the window alert to work as a hint that my function is working
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of `$window` and `$http`. Always follow the order in which you inject your dependencies.

your `function` should be `function($scope, $http, $window)`

Comment: Correct answer, replicated here: https://plnkr.co/edit/Z40BPDC6BsQ2qHeMApbC?p=preview

Comment: Thank you Ravi Teja